# How can I see/select UVs that are mirrored

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, mirror

I have around a hundred models which have some UVs that are mirrored. I need to find those UVs are unmirror them. Unfortunately, it is very difficult to do and I was hoping there would be a way to see which UVs are mirrored or better yet, be able to select all of them. Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Also, I am completely new to 3d modeling. I've been showing this picture which I think is a screenshot of maya and I'm told that the red UVs are the ones that are mirrored. I'm hoping blender has similar functionality.

[image]

Comment: The easiest way to spot them would be by using a Texture with lettters/numbers to see where the symbols are mirrored. 
As for writing a script that detects them... Unfortunately that's not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

There is a option for that in "magic uv" addon which is biuld in Blender. After enabling an addon, you should see "magic uv" tab on the right side of the uv editor window (press "n" to show/hide entire toolbar). Expand "Uv manipulation", enable "select tool", click on "flipped".